# How to catch selected value from Android Menu Radio Values

Tags: java, android

I've created a radio button menu list ..

```
    final CharSequence[] items = { "3 sec", "5 sec", "7 sec" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Change Wallpaper Every..");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }); 

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    builder.show();
```

what I want to do is to catch the selected value from the above Char Sequence and to put to a variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried with `If ... else`

First, I declare a private variable with a default value

```
private static int myChoice = 3000; //3000 is Millisecond = 3 sec
```

Then, I've added a condition after `Toast.makeText( )`

```
                final CharSequence[] items = { "3 sec", "5 sec", "7 sec", "10 sec" }
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (items[item] == "3 sec") {
                        myChoice = 3000;
                    } else if (items[item] == "5 sec") {
                        myChoice = 5000;
                    } else if (items[item] == "7 sec") {
                        myChoice = 7000;
                    } else if (items[item] == "10 sec") {
                        myChoice = 10000;
                    }
                }
```

I got the value in this way.

Answer (score 2):

The selected item is the one with the index `item`, the corresponding String is `items[item]`.

A typical pattern to catch a selection is like this:

```
public class SomeDialog {

   final CharSequence[] items = { "3 sec", "5 sec", "7 sec" };
   int choice = -1; 

   //...

   public void someMethod() {
     //...
     builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    choice = item;  // <-- now we store the selection to a class member
                }
            }); 
      // ... 
   }

   public String getSelection() {
     return items[choice];  // <-- this allows another class to read the current selection
                            //     often called after the dialog has been closed
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

An alternative would be making the Dialog (or part of the Dialog) [observable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The Dialog would fire an event whenever the selction changed and anyone interested in the selected value would listen to this event source.

Comment: `getSelection()` would be an added mess for `AlertDialog` s which are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

I use factories for this kind of things:

```
public interface ChoiceListener {
    void onPositiveResult(String choice);
}

public static AlertDialog getWallpaperDialog(Context ctx,
        final String[] options, int choice, final ChoiceListener listener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    // set title, buttons, etc.
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(options, choice, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            listener.onPositiveResult(options[which]);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Suggestions: store string arrays in resources (e.g. `strings.xml`) & stick to indexes instead  of strings for preferences.